# Java compatibility

Tags: java

I'm running the same code on two machines. One (windows 7 64) uses:

```
java version "1.7.0"
java<TM> SE Runtime Environment <build 1.7.0-b147>
Java HotSpot<TM> 64-Bit Server VM <build 21.0-b17, mixed code>
```

and the other (linux 64) uses:

```
java version "1.6.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_10-b33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0-b15, mixed mode)
```

I'm getting different outputs. I think it's the VM because I copied the .class files, ran those, and still got different outputs.
Can anyone tell what could cause this?

EDIT:

The code is at http://pastebin.com/5EmYFkYn

The output should vary in between runs, yet not as drastically as it is between those two machines.

Comment: Can you show us your outputs? what output you're getting and what output you were expecting? also code?

Comment: @PradeepSimha The code is around 600 lines, and simulates servers/clients using exponential distributions. Should I just paste it here?

Comment: Do you get the exact same output if you run your code twice on the same machine? Simulation sounds like it has some random aspects and therefore you can never expect the same output.

Comment: Just paste relevant portion of code, and relevent outputs

Comment: With the current state, there is absolutely no clue for any of us to begin to guess what was exactly the problem.

Comment: There are just too many possibilities: code may use properties, environment variables, contents of files, output of other programs, to name a few.

Comment: @nhahtdh I posted the code. In my opinion, the relevant classes are the simulator class, which iterates over generic containers, and the exponential class, which generates exponential distributed numbers.

Comment: Is there a reason why the Linux box and the Windows box run different versions of Java? (I mean except for not knowing how to update packages on your Linux distribution)

Comment: @Shmoopy looked at your code. Why do you expect the output not to be different, if you have random components.

Comment: @Philipp One is my machine, and the other is not mine to decide.

Comment: Can you show us the simplest form of the code which shows the problem? And tell us what the problem is?  BTW Both version of Java are fairly old, both have many bugs fixed since then.  Can you compare Java 7 update 10 with Java 6 update 37?

Comment: When it's your machine, you should downgrade it to Java 6. The development environment and the production environment should always be as similar as possible.

Comment: @Shmoopy Your question boils downt to: Why does random() return random numbers? 'nuff said.

Comment: @Ingo Not really. When you run the code on windows the output is around 3 times larger than the one on the linux machine. It's consistent between runs (on both machines), and I expect both to behave the same.

Comment: @jlordo The function that uses Random() should converge the same on both machines.

Comment: @Shmoopy Please initialize your random generator with a fixed seed, then run on both machines. Only then a comparison makes sense.

Comment: @Ingo It worked! It behaves the same now. Thanks!

Comment: @Shmoopy, converging towards a limit within a finite number of steps isn't the same as producing the exact same result (since you can't iterate infinitely, you need to make an approximation as to when to stop). Different random generators initialised differently may produce different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get ~1.78 with Java 6 update 31 and ~3.8 with Java 7 update 7 on the same Linux box.

However if I get the random seed with `new Random(1)` or some other number I get the same result.  e.g. 1 always produces ~ 0.79 for the third number.

Looking at the code for how the random seed is created, the code is completely different and I suspect the nextDouble() isn't as random as it should be i.e. your values should vary more and it should matter so much how the seed was set.

---

I get different results every time I run it on the same machine with the same version of Java.  Most likely as there are random elements in the code.

```
499470 0 3.7783771731449503 10000.355400975242 0.07565041858446288 42
499430 0 3.8374792234448916 10001.384837656298 0.07684781955465791 53
499604 0 3.868284648304009 10000.698947869778 0.07743242690681965 57
499114 0 3.822480313596936 10001.023197561686 0.07659315164172079 46
500030 0 3.8653339884104576 10000.112232176294 0.077302909223347 43
```

Since it is different between runs on the same machine, I would expect them to be different on different machines, and different versions of Java as well.

I would still seriously consider getting a newer version of Java than Java 7 "update nothing" or a version of Java 6 which is four years old.

Comment: Thanks for testing. The 3rd output (~3.77) on Linux is around 1.15. This is very significant.

Comment: I get ~1.78 with Java 6 update 31 and ~3.8 with Java 7 update 7 on the same Linux box.

Comment: If I get the seed with `new Random(1)` on both version I get ~0.79. I will look at how the seed is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the machines runs java 6, the other java 7. There are numerous changes between these versions:

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/

In addition, there are likely a lot of detail changes which might affect behavior which is not described or undefined according to the documentation.

Which of these differences might affect your program is impossible to tell without looking at the sourcecode or at least knowing what kind of differences in output you are talking about.